# Why is my angular directive (using compile) blocking input in some scenarios?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I've written a directive which adds a class based on a condition - see snippet at the bottom of the question.

It works as expected in the following simple usage scenario for a required field:

`<input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="$crtl.lastName" my-directive="$crtl.isLastNameValid()" required>`

However in the following scenario where I have two dependent elements using `ng-required` it blocks input on the element in which I don't type initially.

i.e. if I type in `email` it blocks input into `mobile` and visa versa - other than that is works fine, used as:

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="$ctrl.emailAddress"
   ng-required="$ctrl.mobileNumber.length === 0" my-directive="$ctrl.isEmailValid()">  

<input type="tel" id="mobile" name="mobile" ng-model="$ctrl.mobileNumber"
   pattern="(?:\+?61|0)4 ?(?:(?:[01] ?[0-9]|2 ?[0-57-9]|3 ?[1-9]|4 ?[7-9]|5 ?[018]) ?[0-9]|3 ?0 ?[0-5])(?: ?[0-9]){5}" 
   ng-required="$ctrl.emailAddress.length === 0" my-directive="$ctrl.isMobileValid()">
```

Where am I going wrong? I am compiling the element based on the condition passed in I am assuming it has something to do with that?

```
export const myDirective = ($compile: ng.ICompileService): ng.IDirective => {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        compile: (element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes): ng.IDirectivePrePost => {

            var condition = attrs['myDirective'];
            element.removeAttr('my-directive');

            if (condition) {
                element.attr('ng-class', `{ "validation-error": ${condition} }`);

                return {
                    pre: () => { },
                    post: ($scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery) => {
                        $compile(element)($scope);
                    }
                };
            }

            return {
                pre: () => { },
                post: () => { }
            };
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a directive that adds and removes a class based on a condition defined by an angular expression:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return function postLink (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.myDirective, function(newBool) {
            if (newBool) {
                attrs.$addClass("validation-error");
            } else {
                attrs.$removeClass("validation-error");
            };
        });
    };
});
```

On every digest cycle, the directive evaluates the Angular Expression defined by the `my-directive` attribute and if the expression changes, it either adds or removes the `validation-error` class based in the truthyness of the Angular Expression.